# Unexpected symbol: COMMA error from json file

Tags: json

I'm using Talend ETL Tool and extracting data from json files and storing them in Mysql database.

But I get the error while reading in very first json. For reading json I'm using tExtractJSONFileds component.

I'm sure about the configuation set up in talend etl tool its right. I believe there is some problem in json file.

While extracting the component shows error like this

```
Exception in component tExtractJSONFields_1
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected symbol: COMMA
    at de.odysseus.staxon.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:218)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.<init>(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:65)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:148)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:44)
    at de.odysseus.staxon.base.AbstractXMLInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(AbstractXMLInputFactory.java:118)
```

I dont know how to deal with JSONs, So Acc to this error can anyone help me where could be the error in JSON file ?

Is there any value passed as NULL or something else ?

Sample JSON

```
[
    [, {
        "tstamp": "123456",
        "event": "tgegfght",
        "is_duplicate": false,
        "farm": "dyhetygdht",
        "uid": "tutyvbrtyvtrvy",
        "clientip": "52351365136",
        "device_os_label": "MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_7",
        "device_browser_label": "MOZILLA_FIREFOX",
        "geo_country_code": "MA",
        "geo_region_code": "55",
        "geo_city_name_normalized": "agadir",
        "referer": "www.abc.com",
        "txn": "etvevv5r",
        "txn_isnew": true,
        "publisher_id": 126,
        "adspot_id": 11179502,
        "ad_spot": 5188,
        "format_id": 1611,
        "misc": {
            "PUBLISHER_FOLDER": "retvrect",
            "NO_PROMO": "rctrctrc",
            "SECTION": "evtrevr",
            "U_COMMON_ALLOW": "0",
            "U_Auth": "0"
        },
        "handler": "uint"
    }, , ]
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Do you have a sample JSON data to show?

Comment: @denchu, Json data is too big, which part you are interested to look at in ? Do you want to copy from anywhere to show it to you ?

Comment: You could try checking if the json file is valid via http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @denchu, please check, I have pasted sample json for you in question

Comment: You see the empty commas with no values? Most likely it's the one throwing the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra empty commas in your sample json.

Your Sample Json should look like

```
  [{
        "tstamp": "123456",
        "event": "tgegfght",
        "is_duplicate": false,
        "farm": "dyhetygdht",
        "uid": "tutyvbrtyvtrvy",
        "clientip": "52351365136",
        "device_os_label": "MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_7",
        "device_browser_label": "MOZILLA_FIREFOX",
        "geo_country_code": "MA",
        "geo_region_code": "55",
        "geo_city_name_normalized": "agadir",
        "referer": "www.abc.com",
        "txn": "etvevv5r",
        "txn_isnew": true,
        "publisher_id": 126,
        "adspot_id": 11179502,
        "ad_spot": 5188,
        "format_id": 1611,
        "misc": {
            "PUBLISHER_FOLDER": "retvrect",
            "NO_PROMO": "rctrctrc",
            "SECTION": "evtrevr",
            "U_COMMON_ALLOW": "0",
            "U_Auth": "0"
        },
        "handler": "uint"
    }]
```

OR

```
[
    {
        "somethinghere": "its value"
    },
   "somethingelse": "its value"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample json is not valid json, due to the spurious extra commas on the second and last lines.  Json only allows commas BETWEEN elements of a vector or object, and empty elements are not allowed.